# How to set high video quality by default in VideoJs?

Tags: vuejs3, video.js

I have a problem regarding video quality loss when playing a video in videojs. Stack: Vue3 (script setup), Vite, Typescript. Currently, when the video starts, its quality decreases drastically with every second. How can I set the default high video quality? I will also add that I don't want to display the controls.

```
    player = videojs(
        player_ref.value as HTMLVideoElement,
        {
            loop: true,
            fluid: false,
            autoplay: false,
            sources: [
                {
                    src: reel.value?.video_hls_url,
                    type: 'application/x-mpegURL',
                },
            ],
            playsinline: true,
            preload: 'metadata',
            disablePictureInPicture: true,
            suggestedQuality: 'hd',
        },
        () => {
            player.log('onPlayerReady', player);
            player.play();
        }
    );
    player.options.autoSetup = false;
```

I tested playback on real mobile devices. On Android, the movie plays, but it loses quality as described, while on IOS, the movie initially played in good quality, but it was started via the system player, and since I don't want it, I added `disablePictureInPicture: true` and now there is only a black screen on IOS, but the system player no longer opens.